# using functions to produce a euro converter in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, function, return

I want to make a sort of pound to euro converter using a function.
What I want the system to do it, when you type in your number into the text box and press convert, I want the Euro converted number in the label to show up.

I believe this is done by telling the system to multiply any number typed in by the conversion rate of 1.34509.

But I dont think im doing it correctly.

```
Protected Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click

    End Sub

    Function Convert(txtPound As Decimal) As Decimal
        'declare variable to store answer 
        Dim Converter As Decimal
        'calculate the Answer
        Converter = Convert(txtPound * 1.34509)
        'return the Answer
        Return Converter

    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Apart from not reading the value, calling the function or setting a label in your click event handler, the `Convert` function looks almost OK - you need to get a `decimal` out of the text box.

Comment: Six lines that can be compressed to one: `Return txtPound * 1.34509`. Incidentally, that’s a really poor variable name: the `txt` prefix implies that the type is `String`, not `Decimal`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - `txtPound` is most likely the name of the control.

Comment: txtPound is the name of the text box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will suits your requirement,

***Event:***

```
'---This is the procedure which is going to handle your btnGo's Click Event
Protected Sub btnGo_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click

'---Here we are calling the function Convert(Decimal) by passing the txtPound's text
   msgbox(Convert(Decimal.Parse(txtPound.Text)))

End Sub
```

***Function:***

```
'---This function will receive the passed value as xValue and execute its code  
Private Function Convert(xValue as Decimal) as Decimal

'---This line will do the conversion and simply send back the result to the caller.  
   return (xValue * 1.34509)

End Function
```

And Furtherly if you need more clarification on it, then just refer [this.](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/net/vbnet.html)

Comment: @user1944225 MsgBox is a dialogue box with a OK button affixed on it. It will simply display the text that we are passing in it. Ex: MsgBox("Hello world")

Comment: Also can xValue be changed to a different name, or must it stay as xValue

Comment: @user1944225 No, not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the entered amount and convert it to a decimal before you can calculate:

```
Dim pounds As Decimal
pounds = Decimal.Parse(txtPound.Text)
Converter = Convert(pounds * 1.34509)
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how would you produce this in a function format

Comment: @user1944225 - I don't follow. These statements can be put into a function, the same as you already have.

Comment: ok, also how does the "return" aspect work, and what does it do

Comment: @user1944225 - You really need to get yourself a VB.NET textbook. These are questions that would be covered in any beginner book.

Comment: yes i now, but it hasnt arrived. thats why im asking for help, so can you help me plz